# How can nested minimum operators be simplified?

Tags: functions

Suppose I have defined an operator $\oplus$ such that $x\oplus y =\min (x+y, k)$, where $x, y,k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ (positive real numbers) and + is the normal addition operator. The purpose of $k$ is to restrict the addition to an upper bound. Let $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ as well and suppose I wish to do the addition with my custom addition operator.
$$(x\oplus y)\oplus z =\min (\min (x+y,k) + z, k) $$
The custom defined sum will now map to the domain $[0, k]$. The question now is the following: since $k$ is the same for both minimumn operators, can I simplify this nested minimum operator into a single one, i.e. can I write the following?
$$\min (\min (x+y,k) + z, k) = \min (x + y + z, k)$$
By logical reasoning I would say if the inner minimum is restricted by $k$, then so would the outer one be (since $x,y,z\geq 0$), and the answer would be $k$. Conversely if $x+y$ is less than $k$, then the inner minimum serves no purpose.

I have searched for this for some hours, but can at no place find any similar question. I would love if anyone could prove this is correct or wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and have given the proof.